# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) with linux-image-5.4.0-128-generic

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg

I want to install openssl (which already installed, but I forget), after I execute
***sudo apt install openssl*** in bash, some error occur in my shell:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
openssl is already the newest version (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 103 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-image-5.4.0-128-generic (5.4.0-128.144) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.4.0-128-generic (5.4.0-128.144) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-128-generic
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.4.0-128-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.4.0-128-generic package post-installation script subprocess was killed by signal (Terminated)
Terminated
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.4.0-128-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

my os is ubuntu server 20.04

Comment: So, fyi, `openssl` is part of the default install you don't need to install it separately.  However, what you're running into is another package that was being updated, etc. is broken because it has no space, etc.  You should start by doing `sudo apt remove linux-image-5.4.0-128-generic`, then do `sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`, and then make sure that `linux-image-generic` is properly installed with all dependent packages as well.  That should get you back to 'functional'.

Comment: Thanks . When I run apt autoremove, an error occur like this :
 
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 103 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/12.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 86.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 141764 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-5.4.0-128_5.4.0-128.144_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.4.0-128 (5.4.0-128.144) over (5.4.0-128.144) ...
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg exited unexpectedly